# Tensorflow saving subclass model which has multiple arguments to call() method

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I am following the tensorflow neural machine translation tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention

I am trying to save the Encoder and Decoder models which are subclasses of the tf.keras.Model and work properly during training and inference, however I want to save the models. When I try to do so I get the following error:

```
TypeError: call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'initial_state'
```

Here is the code:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_matrix, n_units, batch_size):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.n_units = n_units
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_matrix.shape[1], weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=True, mask_zero=True)
        self.lstm = LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, recurrent_initializer="glorot_uniform")

    def call(self, input_utterence, initial_state):
        input_embed = self.embedding(input_utterence)
        encoder_states, h1, c1 = self.lstm(input_embed, initial_state=initial_state)
        return encoder_states, h1, c1

    def create_initial_state(self):
        return tf.zeros((self.batch_size, self.n_units))

encoder = Encoder(vocab_size, embedding_matrix, LSTM_DIM, BATCH_SIZE)
# do some training...
tf.saved_model.save(decoder, "encoder_model")
```

I also tried to make the call method take one input list argument only and unpack the variables I need within the method but then I get the following error when trying to save:

```
File "C:\Users\Fady\Documents\Machine Learning\chatbot\models\seq2seq_model.py", line 32, in call
input_utterence, initial_state = inputs
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can export the model successfully if you package your inputs in a list. You also need to specify the input signatures to export your model, here your code with slight modifications which works

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM
import numpy as np
print('TensorFlow: ', tf.__version__)


vocab_size = 10000
LSTM_DIM = 256
BATCH_SIZE = 16
embedding_matrix = np.random.randn(vocab_size, 300)

class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_matrix, n_units, batch_size):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.n_units = n_units
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_matrix.shape[1], weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=True, mask_zero=True)
        self.lstm = LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, recurrent_initializer="glorot_uniform")


    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):
        input_utterence, initial_state = inputs
        input_embed = self.embedding(input_utterence)
        encoder_states, h1, c1 = self.lstm(input_embed, initial_state=initial_state)
        return encoder_states, h1, c1


    def create_initial_state(self):
        return tf.zeros((self.batch_size, self.n_units))

random_input = tf.random.uniform(shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 3], maxval=vocab_size, dtype=tf.int32)


encoder = Encoder(vocab_size, embedding_matrix, LSTM_DIM, BATCH_SIZE)

initial_state = [encoder.create_initial_state(), encoder.create_initial_state()]
_ = encoder([random_input, initial_state]) # required so that encoder.build is triggered


tf.saved_model.save(encoder, "encoder_model", signatures=encoder.call.get_concrete_function(
         [
             tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32, name='input_utterence'), 
             [
                 tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, LSTM_DIM], dtype=tf.float32, name='initial_h'), 
                 tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, LSTM_DIM], dtype=tf.float32, name='initial_c')
             ]
         ]))

loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('encoder_model')
loaded_model([random_input, initial_state])
```

output:

```
TensorFlow:  2.2.0-rc1
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/dl_user/tf_stable/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: encoder_model/assets
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(16, 3, 256), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[[-0.06000457,  0.02422162, -0.05310762, ..., -0.01340707,
           0.12212028, -0.02747637],
         [ 0.13303193,  0.3119418 , -0.17995344, ..., -0.10185111,
           0.09568192,  0.06919193],
         [-0.08075664, -0.11490613, -0.20294832, ..., -0.14999194,
           0.02177649,  0.05538464]],

        [[-0.03792192, -0.08431012,  0.03687581, ..., -0.1768839 ,
          -0.10469476,  0.08730042],
         [-0.02956271,  0.43850696, -0.07400024, ...,  0.04097629,
           0.209705  ,  0.27194855],
         [ 0.02529916,  0.18367583, -0.11409087, ...,  0.0458075 ,
           0.2065246 ,  0.22976378]],

        [[ 0.04196627,  0.08302739,  0.02218204, ...,  0.07388053,
          -0.05696848, -0.31895265],
         [-0.00536443,  0.1566213 , -0.22412768, ...,  0.10560389,
           0.20187919, -0.1896591 ],
         [ 0.26364946,  0.13163888,  0.14586888, ...,  0.19517538,
           0.17677066, -0.40476215]],

        ...,

        [[ 0.10999472,  0.07398727,  0.23443945, ..., -0.1912791 ,
          -0.0195728 ,  0.11717851],
         [ 0.03978832,  0.07587367,  0.16567066, ..., -0.29463592,
           0.05950819,  0.0242265 ],
         [ 0.2505787 ,  0.15849623,  0.06635283, ..., -0.17969091,
           0.12549783, -0.11459641]],

        [[-0.20408148,  0.04629526,  0.00601436, ...,  0.21321473,
           0.04952445, -0.0129672 ],
         [-0.14671509,  0.2911171 ,  0.13047697, ..., -0.03531414,
          -0.16794083,  0.01575338],
         [-0.08337164,  0.08723269,  0.16235027, ...,  0.07919721,
           0.05701642,  0.15379705]],

        [[-0.2747393 ,  0.24351111, -0.05829309, ..., -0.00448833,
           0.07568972,  0.03978251],
         [-0.16282909, -0.04586324, -0.0054924 , ...,  0.11050001,
           0.1312355 ,  0.16555254],
         [ 0.07759799, -0.07308074, -0.10038756, ...,  0.18139914,
           0.07769153,  0.1375772 ]]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(16, 256), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[-0.08075664, -0.11490613, -0.20294832, ..., -0.14999194,
          0.02177649,  0.05538464],
        [ 0.02529916,  0.18367583, -0.11409087, ...,  0.0458075 ,
          0.2065246 ,  0.22976378],
        [ 0.26364946,  0.13163888,  0.14586888, ...,  0.19517538,
          0.17677066, -0.40476215],
        ...,
        [ 0.2505787 ,  0.15849623,  0.06635283, ..., -0.17969091,
          0.12549783, -0.11459641],
        [-0.08337164,  0.08723269,  0.16235027, ...,  0.07919721,
          0.05701642,  0.15379705],
        [ 0.07759799, -0.07308074, -0.10038756, ...,  0.18139914,
          0.07769153,  0.1375772 ]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(16, 256), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[-0.32829475, -0.18770668, -0.2956414 , ..., -0.2427501 ,
          0.03146099,  0.16033864],
        [ 0.05112522,  0.6664379 , -0.19836858, ...,  0.10015503,
          0.511694  ,  0.51550364],
        [ 0.3379809 ,  0.7145362 ,  0.22311993, ...,  0.372106  ,
          0.25914627, -0.81374717],
        ...,
        [ 0.36742535,  0.29009506,  0.13245934, ..., -0.4318537 ,
          0.26666188, -0.20086129],
        [-0.17384854,  0.22998339,  0.27335796, ...,  0.09973672,
          0.10726923,  0.47339764],
        [ 0.22148325, -0.11998752, -0.16339599, ...,  0.31903535,
          0.20365229,  0.28087002]], dtype=float32)>)
```

Comment: Spent hours on the docs trying to figure this out. I wish they told you somewhere (or I'm just missing it). I know multiple inputs aren't that common, but I would be nice to have a note somewhere.